# the language doesn't get back to original language

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to have a bilingual website(in Englih and German) using **Resource.resx** I can successfuly change the language of a page to german but Ican't go back to English.This is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Session["Lan"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();


                if (Session["Lan"].ToString() == "de-DE")
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
                    Label2.Text = Resources.Resource.Here;
                    HyperLink1.Text = Resources.Resource.Signup;
                }
```

How can I solve this Problem?

**Edit:**
I've set Autopost property of Dropdownbox to true and put my block of code to **ispostback** like this:

```
Session["Lan"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["Lan"].ToString() == "de-DE")
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

                    Label1.Text = Resources.Resource.Quick_routes_offers_the_opportunity_to_manage_and_analyze_the_recorded_routes_The_format_of_your_route_must_be_GPX_format_;
                    Label2.Text = Resources.Resource.Here;
                    HyperLink1.Text = Resources.Resource.Signup;
                }

            }
```

but I think if the language is not "de" the original text of my lables should appear ,Why  this idea doesn't work?

Comment: Do a postback after the user selects a new language from the dropdown.

Comment: Where do you set the language to English?  You have a conditional here to set it to German, but you don't set it back.  Are you relying on a non-German-selected postback to set it back?  When you perform that postback, what happens in this code?

Comment: @David: I didn't set thelanguage for English,how should I do this job to return back to english.to be honest I have a Master page and some menu items on it this idee works good for that items but here not

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I didn't get what you mean,where should I put post back?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1444616.aspx/1

Comment: thank you I put post back in my code and edited my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, put an `else` below if.

```
    else 
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

                Label1.Text = Resources.Resource.Quick_routes_offers_the_opportunity_to_manage_and_analyze_the_recorded_routes_The_format_of_your_route_must_be_GPX_format_;
                Label2.Text = Resources.Resource.Here;
                HyperLink1.Text = Resources.Resource.Signup;
            }
```

Comment: @Kabi, I forgot to mention, put the `if` condition outside `If(Page.IsPostBack)`